# get the mutual friends in facebook API Android application

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

Hy guys, i am try to get the mutual friends between the logged user and other users by belwo method but i got empty data node although the error is `null`. any help regarding this issue.

```
    private void getMutualFriends() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "id,name,picture");
        getFriendsIds().put("100005132166273", "");
        RequestBatch requestBatch = new RequestBatch();
        for (final String friendId : getFriendsIds().keySet()) {
            requestBatch.add(new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "/me/mutualfriends/" + friendId, params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    Log.i("Result: " , response.toString());
                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                    if (graphObject != null) {
                        if (graphObject.getProperty("id") != null) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }));
        }
        requestBatch.executeAsync();
    }
```

I always got this response `{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}.`

I replace the request creation by this also `"new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), "me/mutualfriends/" + friendId, null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback().......`

And got the same response.

I will execute the method about 1000 time so i used Facebook request batch if you know better method lets me know please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I might be a bit naive here, but maybe the users you're checking have no mutual friends?

Are you familiar with the "Graph API" explorer? It's very useful:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Try pasting your url (remember to replace 'friendsId' with the user you're checking against) and see what you get.

Comment: you are right the two testing users have no mutual friends :(